# Composite Primary Key for a Content Type

Tags: nodes

Is there any way to create a composite primary key or equivalent for a content type in D7? I really need a way to stop the duplicate content for the same content type.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way to do this is with the [Unique Field](http://drupal.org/project/unique_field).  This provides a WYSIWYG interface for adding node validation to the node save form to check one or more fields' uniqueness.

The module is not bulletproof, though.  There are some scenarios where you can get around it.

> This module is intended to function when a node is being validated prior to being created or updated. It does not prevent nodes from being programmatically saved with duplicate values (including when a node is reverted to an earlier revision).

The reason is that the check is done at the code level via validation and is not a database enforcement via composite keys.

A similar module, that also provides a lot more features in addition to the uniqueness check, is [Field Validation](http://drupal.org/project/field_validation).

If you want to give the composite key thing a shot, I would make a test site and edit one of the field tables by hand to make the composite key.  Then install/enable Unique Field and see what happens with the cases that the module doesn't cover.

Comment: Unique field looks very interesting, thanks for the heads up on that one

Comment: The field validation looks awesome, i was looking for something to auto fill other fields. this is perfect. thanks a ton

Answer (score 2):

The field data is stored in separate database tables (or even in a completely different storage system) so not really, no.

As an *extremely* low tech solution you could attach a validation handler to the node form, which checks to see if a node with the same details has already been added. If it has, you can set an error and ask the user to fix the problem.

This is just skeleton code and will need a fair bit of customising:

```
function MYMODULE_node_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  $field_first_field = $form_state['values']['field_first_field'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
  $field_second_field = $form_state['values']['field_second_field'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
  // etc...

  $query = new EntityFieldQuery;
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'my_content_type')
    ->fieldCondition('field_first_field', 'value', $field_first_field)
    ->fieldCondition('field_second_field', 'value', $field_second_field);

  $results = $query->execute();

  if (!empty($results['node'])) {
    form_set_error('', 'A piece of content with the same first field and second field has already been added. Please revise these fields.');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even more lowe tech als Clive's answer would be to add a unique index to the value column of the field tables in the DB.

However fields default storage isn't meant to be used that way. You will get db errors when it commes to save different revisions or language versions of a field.

But this solution makes 100% sure that you'll never have duplicate values of a vield value.